# Validate the form before adding the loop div

Tags: jquery, loops, jquery-validate

I have a form which has all the fields as mandatory. And I have a button called Add person to create an extra fields to enter details of extra persons.

You can heck the validation by clicking on the submit button.

And if you click in the add person button, it wont generate an extra field's div unless the above 2 fields are filled (address and zip).

So what I need is I need to show an alert as well, when add person button is clicked.

And When ever user click on the add button, it should not allow them to generate another div (.loop) unless previous person details are filled up.

here is the code and  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/39/)**

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#signupForm").validate({
        rules: {            
            address: {
                required: true,
            },
            zip: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            },      

        },
        messages: {         
            address: {
                required: "<br />Please provide your address",
            },
            zip: "<br />Please enter valid ZIP",        
        }
    });

    var c = 0;

    function HTMLloop(c) {
        return '<div class="loop">\
                  <strong>Person ' + c + '</strong><br/> \
                  <input type="text" name="firstName' + c + '"/> \
                  <input type="text" name="lastName' + c + '"/> \
                  <input type="text" name="mail' + c + '"/> \
                  <input type="text" name="company' + c + '"/> \
                  <input type="text" name="company' + c + '"/> \
                  <div class="remove">remove</div> \
               </div>';
    }

    $('.test').on('click', function () {
        if(!$("#signupForm").valid()){
            return;
        }

        if (c<5) $('#loops').append( HTMLloop(++c) );
    });
    $('#loops').on('click','.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        c--;
        $('#loops').find('.loop').each(function(i,e){
            $('strong', this).text( $('strong', this).text().replace( /\d+/g , ' '+(i+1) ) );
            $('input', this).each(function(){
                this.name = this.name.replace( /\d+/g , (i+1) );
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: So what's you problem now? Do you want to show a alert message by clicking on Add Person button?

Comment: yes. Basically 2 things should happen 1st is to show the vaidation msg to blank fields and an alert box. 1st one is happenig there, all I need is to show the alert box and the same process when add person is  clicked next time

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/40/)

Comment: That s exactly fine for alert box. The other thing is u fill both the address and zip fields then u can create an additional set of fields by clicking on the add person button, here it should not allow user to create second set unless first set's fields are filled up

Comment: So if user not enter all 5 fields then you don't want to show next set of 5 fields?

Comment: I'm adding this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rw9ns/40/).

```
$('.test').on('click', function () {
    if(!$("#signupForm").valid()){
        alert("Please enter mandatory fields.");
        return;
    }

    if (c<5) $('#loops').append( HTMLloop(++c) );
});
```

Here in the above condition you can check if any fields is blank then you don't allow to add another set. Hope this will help you.